# Why is there a large space between my TextView rows in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have this `RecyclerView` that I want to put items in but the spacing between text rows is to much. I want the space between text to be closer vertically.

Here´s a picture:

[image]

Here´s the xml for one row:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/history_line"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/history_line_layout"
android:layout_height="200dp">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15625"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="country"
    android:maxLines="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/administrative_area_level_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/administrative_area_level_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/administrative_area_level_2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/administrative_area_level_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/administrative_area_level_1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/locality"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locality"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="LOCALITY"
    android:maxLines="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/route"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/administrative_area_level_2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/route"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="ROUTE"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timestamp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locality" />

<com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="time"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/route"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49" />
```

Would really like som help with this because in my xml there´s no margins set and still looks like this:

Comment: Try setting `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom` to zero. Also check the top and bottom padding.

Comment: And anyway, you can create the same layout in Android Studio and change the parameters on spot and see if that solves your problem

Comment: Im using Android Studio layout design manager like you suggest. I did not work setting `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom` to 0dp

Comment: How about removing `android:paddingTop="5dp"` from `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Thanks again @zed that was the reason i missed that GHrrmm. Put that in an answer so I can accept it and close question.

Comment: Very thoughtful of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the padding of the parent constraint layout:

```
     android:paddingTop="5dp"
```